# What is Directional Quantile Regression?

Tags: regression, quantile-regression, circular-statistics

I am coming from a computer science background and I am reading this research paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X10001636

There are so many math equations that I don't really understand.

Question: what is directional quantile regression?

Comment: This work is in Mathematical Statistics, so don't blame yourself for not understanding the equations. What is your general goal? Because if you are interested in applying their methods, it is probably not feasible to do so currently unless you are willing to implement the algorithms yourself.

Comment: @KeesMulder I current goal is to just understand it and see if it can be applied to data analysis

Comment: I don't know the answer, but considering the niche-ness of the topic I think you may not find an answer here. If that happens, your best bet would be to look at the package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modQR/index.html) and to e-mail those authors directly for guidance.